Python: Query Mongodb collection through webservice. Unable to parse Query, curl is working fine
Below curl is working fine,
curl --request POST --header "x-snow-auth: Token" --data "[{ $match: { $and: [ { "_sequence": { $gt: $cnt } }, { _deleted: 0 } ] } }, {$sort: {_sequence: 1}}, {$limit: 10000} ]"  https://server/collect?collection=abc > output.text
but when I am tying the same thing in Python
dataObj= '[{ $match: { $and: [ { _sequence: { $gt: -1 } }, { _deleted: 0 } ] } }, {$sort: {_sequence: 1}}, {$limit: 10000} ]'
x = requests.post('https://server/collect?collection=abc', json = dataObj , headers = hedr)
print(x.text)
I am getting the below error. I also tried using json.dumps(dataObj), still no use
{
"cause": ["readStartArray can only be called when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING."],
"error": "invalid query: '"[{ $match: { $and: [ { _sequence: { $gt: -1 } }, { _deleted: 0 } ] } }, {$sort: {_sequence: 1}}, {$limit: 10000} ]"', error: 'Unable to parse query'",
"url": "/collect",
"status": 400
}
curl is working but the same thing I am not able to achieve in python.
Thanks

In the requests.post call, try data=dataObj instead of json = dataObj. When you specify it as json, the requests library will try to convert that to a json string. But your dataObj is already a json string. Also, improve the formatting of your code, make use of block quotes ```like this```.
